# Problem setting PHP SESSION variables within cross-domain iframe

Tags: php, iframe, cross-domain, session-variables

Coles Notes version:

`index.php?map_id=foo` is loaded into iframe on www.not-my-domain.com. index sets `SESSION['map_id']` = foo. Flash file tries to get `SESSION['map_id']` thru Authenticate.php, but Authenticate.php has no values set for *any* `SESSION` varaibles.

-- Only first-load, cross domain issue.

Verbose:

I have an index while where I set: `SESSION['map_id'] = foo`

The index file then loads a flash file. When initialized, the flash accesses an 'Authenticate.php' file which echo's out the `SESSION['map_id']` and is loaded into flash via `LoadVars`. Flash then displays the appropriate data.
*This step cannot be done another way*

This all works just fine on our main site. The issue comes when we try to port out to other sites by providing iframe embed codes:

```
<iframe src="http://www.mydomain.com/?map_id=foo&code=bar" ... ></iframe>
```

On a fresh load of the embed code from another site (www.anotherdomain.com), it seems that the `SESSION` variables have been destroyed, as flash simply says they are empty. ( `$map_id` outputs a blank )

The index file will still properly echo `$map_id` as 'foo', it just seems the 'Authenticate.php' file cannot access the `SESSION` varaibles.

I have ensured `session_start()` is present in all appropriate files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP session ids are passed through cookies by default, but you can't transfer cookies across domains. Try passing the session id through the url instead.

[Here is the appropriate page in the php documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php).

There are a few ways you can get php to pass the session id in the url if it's not being done automatically.

1. You can manually pass the session id in the url (must come before other get variables):

   <iframe src="http://www.mydomain.com/?&map_id=foo&code=bar">
2. You can disable cookies, forcing every request to have the session id automatically added to the url:

   ini_set("session.use_cookies","0");
3. You can edit the url_rewriter.tags setting, which tells PHP which html tags to rewrite with the session id. Here, iframe=src has been added to the default set:

   ini_set("url_rewriter.tags", "a=href,area=href,frame=src,iframe=src,input=src,form=fakeentry");

Comment: So, because the session id isn't passed the first time thru via cookies, the session variables don't know which session they belong to?
If I pass the session id thru the URL, I could then tell the session it's id?

Comment: That's the gist of it. I've updated my response to be a little more clear about how to do that.

Comment: That's a fairly sensitive solution because we're opening this up to the public. It will likely be inserted on someones page with a blogspot type editor. Is there anyway this can be done just with our pages?

Comment: I'm not sure. PHP automatically appends the session id to the url if the client has cookies disabled. Perhaps you could try forcing the this behavior from your end by setting ini_set("session.use_cookies","0"); on your end. I'm not certain this will work, but if it does please post back and I'll edit my answer to include this solution.

Comment: That works fine for links. But what about JS AJAX calls ? How to "easy handle" them ?